# How To Send and Receive JSON With XAMPP PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a XAMPP 7.1.10-0 server running with this index.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
        echo $_POST;
        header("Location:getbooks.php");
        exit;
    } else {    
        echo file_get_contents("login.html");
    }
?>
```

This initially works and displays the login.html file. Then I want to make a ajax call to this file again to switch to another html file. So login.js  does this.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.onclick = function() {
    var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var data = {"username": user, "password": pass};
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.post('index.php', data, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

As you can imagine there is a button that is clicked and when it clicks the Ajax call is made. When I click the button it does not change the header and therefore does not change the page. Would anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `$.post`, and putting the result into the console. You never apply the response to your page. Did you mean to replace the content on your page with whatever is returned in `response`?

Comment: You cannot send a header after echoing something, you will have warnings in your server logs saying headers already sent.

Comment: I thought the index.php would change the header redirecting the page to where I want to go. Is it possible for the php to change what the browser is viewing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect, you can do it in AJAX success method.

`login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        Username: <input id="username" type="text"></input> <br>
        Password: <input id="password" type="password"></input> <br>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var button = document.getElementById("submit");
            button.onclick = function() {
            var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data: {
                    "username" : user,
                    "password" : pass
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    window.location = response;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                }
            });     
            }       
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
        //process the array
        echo "getbooks.php";
    } else {    
        echo file_get_contents("login.html");
    }
?>
```

Aside this, you can also handle the response from PHP in AJAX to update the view of the page without redirection.